# How to test webclient of Disposable type call in Spring Webflux

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

Is it possible to use `stubFor` here?
If yes, how to do it?
If not, how to test this code?

```
    public Mono<Void> trelloCallback(Type payload) {
        webClient.post()
                 .uri(URL)
                 .bodyValue(payload)
                 .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
                 .retrieve()
                 .bodyToMono(Void.class)
                 .subscribe();
        return Mono.empty();
    }
```

Info: If we add `.subscribe` to the code, it runs in the background.

Comment: What is `studFor`? :)

Comment: I am sorry, it's `stubFor` its a function in `WorkMock`. It is being used for mocking an endpoint call in our integration test

Answer (score 0):

I test the result, and I can see `WireMock.stubFor` is working with the `subscribe` call.

For more explanation,
We first create a `WireMock.stubFor` for some endpoint call.
Then we make an actual call using the `webTestClient` to do integration test. And then verify the result using

```
verify(exactly(1), postRequestedFor(urlEqualTo(SOME_URL)));
// For SOME_URL create a `stubFor`
```